# Smell from electrical outlet

Tags: electrical, receptacle, smell

There is s strange smell on my daughter’s bedroom coming from an electrical outlet (smells like burnt). It smells only at night, despite the breaker being off,  it still smells.
Electrician changed the outlet although it looked good. Wires look good.

Ac person came and said vent/furnace ac was good

What is it and how can we fix it

Comment: what kind of electrical outlet is it ? What is normaly plugged in it ?

Comment: What kind of burnt?  Plastic, rubber, wood, hair.

Comment: One night, try turning off the main breaker to see if it still smells.  That will tell you if the issue is electrical or something else.  If it's electrical, the next night turn off half the breakers to help narrow down what might be causing it.  Think about what is on only at night.  Do you have heating only at night?  Or a night light somewhere?  If it's not electrical .... at least you know that.

Comment: What is on the other side of your daughter's bedroom wall? The kitchen of another apartment perhaps?